# how to check if large text is present in page source selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to check if large text is present in page source.
I have used contains method to check but condition becomes false as sequence is not accurate .
I want solution how to just check whether data is present not bothering of the sequence

```
public void demo()
{    
String description="(Large data is present)"; 
String pagesource=driver.getPageSource(); //have also tried with String    source = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText(); String    source = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText();    
if(pagesource.contains(description))
{ System.out.println("Match    Found"); }
else
{ System.out.println("Match Not Found"); }

}
```

Comment: Does your page source have same string? with given character cases?

Comment: Actually when we try using  getPageSource method html tags also comes i tired removing that too but somewhere data does not get matched because of spaces and newline i removed that too and tried using by tag name body and getting text but it does not get the whole data from web page i want some solution where i can just check if data is present without bothering if data is very matching to my description

Answer (score 0):

It seems alphabet Case sensitive issue , Please try condition :

```
   if(pagesource.toLowerCase().contains(description.toLowerCase()))

    {

        System.out.println("Match Found");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Match Not Found");

    }
```

In above , Converting all characters to lowercase of both string and then comparing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want cross check data at particular location, then better to try with gettext(); below example will helps you in both ways

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://seleniumtrainer.com/components/buttons/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("button1")).click();

    //by using if condition with cross check
    try{

        if(driver.findElement(By.id("demo")).isDisplayed()==true){

            System.out.println("clicked correctly");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("U Clicked Button1 text is not displayed. so failing or throwing again to fail test");
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }

    //simply by using testng assertion
    //Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id("demo")).getText(), "U Clicked Button1");

    //using page source
    String pagesource=driver.getPageSource(); 

    if(pagesource.contains("U Clicked Button1")){

        System.out.println("search done correctly from page source");
    }else{

        System.out.println("not found in page source");
    }
```

Thanks